# CanCan Nested Resource Index Action Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have Posts, that are in Feeds.

In order to be able to view the posts in a feed, one must be in the feed.

In my routes, posts are nested under feeds.

In my PostsController, I have:

```
class Api::V1::PostsController < ApiController
  load_resource :network, find_by: :external_id, only: [:index, :create]
  load_resource :post, :through => :network, only: [:create]

  load_resource find_by: :external_id, except: [:create]

  authorize_resource

  def index
    @posts = @network.posts.page(params.has_key?(:page) ? params[:page] : 1).per(15)

  render status: 200,
           json: @posts
  end
```

The corresponding ability:

```
can [:index, :create], Post do |post|
      user.in_feed? post.feed_id
end
```

For some reason, all users pass the authorization though. How would I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of CanCanCan. From the documentation about defining abilities with blocks:

> The block is only evaluated when an actual instance object is present.
>   It is not evaluated when checking permissions on the class (such as in
>   the index action).

Since an instance is not present for either the `index` or `create` actions, the block is never run. You want

```
can [:create, :index], Post if user.in_feed? post.feed_id
```